# Tags problem for Superuser

Tags: support, tags, search

Uservoice was discontinued, so I come here with this.

The concept behind superuser is somewhat different than that of Stackoverflow and Serverfault.

Questions about software are often limited to a certain OS.

Now, if I go look for the tag "Windows", I'll miss all questions tagged "Windows-vista" but not "windows". I'll miss every post which has a varying name without having the Windows tag.

Same thing if I were looking for the tag "search", all questions tagged only as "searching" would be left out.

While not super-important, is there a way to counter this?

Answer (score 9):

[Catch them all with the tilde (~)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1672/please-allow-wildcards-in-tag-searches).

So <kbd>[windows~](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows~)</kbd> will show you all of the following:

- windows
- windows-xp
- windows-7
- but then it goes qwayzee and you get **everything** that starts with <kbd>windows</kbd>.

Comment: **qwayzee** == **crazy**?

Comment: @jjinguy, you're missing the hands in the air.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the auto-conversion (i.e. a search for `bug` on MSO shows only questions tagged with `bug`): You can put the searchword in quotes to circumvent that: `"bug"`.